# Xcode problems with autolayout for iPhone SE size screens

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I am designing an app for iPhone on iOS 11, and I have run into an issue concerning the design of View Controllers. In my [iPhone 6s and above screen design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osomB.png), the text and buttons do not interfere with each other. However, in my [iPhone SE/iPhone 5s screen design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LxuM.png), the text interferes with some of my buttons. As shown in the pictures, the vertical location for the orange button is based off the location of the blue button below. I would like this constraint to remain no matter the screen size of the phone. The vertical location for all of the text above the buttons is based off the top of the view controller.

Is there any way I can keep the vertical location of my text the same for how I currently have it in my iPhone 6s and above screen design while shrinking the vertical constraints or font size of the text for the iPhone SE? Or is there some other way I can avoid having the text and UIButtons interfering with each other?

Edit: I also do not want my design to be a scroll view. I am thinking I may have to simply decrease the size of the text and buttons for all devices.

Comment: Use a UIStackView - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all use scroll view. And For button overlapping to your text, you are missing top constraints (vertical space between button and text) of button. Why scrollview?, because in iphone height are different in SE, 6S, 6+, etc as we know for all iPhone. So when you use scroll view, that time if height less then your content then it is scrollable and contents size remains same for all device.

Comment: I'm trying not to use a scroll view for this. For this particular view controller, I need all words and buttons to appear on the screen without the user having to scroll.

Comment: Then, you need to maintain size of controls particular for this screen, better if you do it programatically. Also, take outlet of vertical spacing constrains and change it as per screen height on condition based, So you can fulfil your requirement.

Comment: I ultimately decided to create my constraints programmatically, and I am getting the results I need.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement i have designed a screen in which i managed all content into a screen without having scrollview for the respective devices.

All you need to do is just design your screen using iPhoneSE and set Yellow button top constraint with 45 constant then you need to set it's relation **"greater then or Equal"** from Size inspector property.

Please find attached screen shot of iPhoneSE and iPhone8+ for more details.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the craziest solution @iOS Team. Look at design. It's totally worst because of gaps are larger then expectation. If I run the same screen with iPhone X or iPhone 8 Plus, What will be output ???

Comment: @PaulMarshal Gap is totally depends on the application UI requirements and based on it we can manage it with the constraints, I think it's still better to use rather then go with the scrollview.